# Fetching from Prisma

Tags: typescript, database, next.js, prisma

I want to fetch a row of data where the accountId is 3 in the table permissions. It should be pretty straight forward. But if i use the code below regardless of if I put in any number. The entire user database is shown. How do I only retrieve accountId 3 record.

```
  const usersPages = useSWRInfinite<TUser[]>(buildKey<Prisma.UserFindManyArgs>('/api/users', {
    where: {
      role: "user",
      createdAt: {
        gte: isValidDate(dateStart) ? formatISO(new Date(dateStart)) : undefined,
        lte: isValidDate(dateEnd) ? formatISO(new Date(dateEnd)) : undefined,
      },
      id: filterId !== '' && !isNaN(Number(filterId)) ? Number(filterId) : undefined,
    },
    include: {
      permissions: {
        include: {
          account: true,
          
          
        },
        where: {
          isOwner : true,
          accountId : 3
         
        },
    
      },
      //@ts-ignore
      userRecord: true,
      // userInfo: true,

    },
    orderBy: {
      // role: "desc",
      createdAt: "desc",
    },
    take,
  }), authorizedFetcher)
```

I've tried removing the isOwner where clause to no avail. It makes no sense because the `id: filterId !== '' && !isNaN(Number(filterId)) ? Number(filterId) : undefined` works just fine.